# Running the Jbilling source code (An ANT project)

Tags: java, ant

I have downloaded the Jbilling Source code. I imported the project in STS (eclipse) but I was unable to run it. Can anyone explain me on how to run that project and what will be the URL to access it in browser?

Comment: I would humbly suggest emailing the mailing list of the jBilling project or perhaps reading their developer documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run build.xml default target. If its jbilling_22 you would need to run jar target first and then default target. you can find the jbilling.war in src\build\deploy folder, copy that in to web-apps of tomcat. 
for jbilling 3, you can run as grails-app which you does not need to execute any ant target

Comment: Thanks scuba. As of now I was able to resolve the issue by following your suggestion: 
"for jbilling 3, you can run as grails-app which you does not need to execute any ant target" and by commenting the test files in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
raher than ANT you can use Grails and run jbilling.

for ANT you can run it by blew ommand
ant test-ws
* ant test-integration

        or, execute single test classes individually

        * ant test-mediation
        * ant test-partners
        * ant test-provisioning
        * ant test-process
```